# apache run php script with exec(*.exe) function

Tags: php, apache2, exe

I m trying to run php script on ubuntu 14.01 server on apache but i can't figure it out how to set apache to execute exe file? Tried permissions, searched conf files, nothing worked do far.

Any advice?
Thanks Klemen

This is my command:

```
<?php

$command='/var/www/html/lastools/bin/las2las.exe'
    .' -i /var/www/html/DRAW/las_na_karti/2843000_1187500.las'
    .' -keep_classification 2'
    .' -odir /var/www/html/DRAW/las_na_karti'
    .' -o /var/www/html/DRAW/las_na_karti/samo_ground.las';   

exec($command);

?>
```

Comment: Are you running some kind of windows emulator on ubuntu? Because exe files are usually for windows systems

Comment: las2las.exe runs on ubuntu 14.04 without wine, if I run this php script from server terminal it is executed without problem

Comment: Did you check the permissions for the files las2las.exe is accessing?

Comment: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/lastools/ and chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/DRAW/las_na_karti/ are the commands i used

Comment: have you looked at the /var/log/apach2/error.log file it should give you the clue what is going wrong

Comment: error.log gives no error vhen trying to run php command